# Ef core create a index from two foreing keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I want to create a index from two foreing keys. My probleme is since the key name is generated by windows the table product and the table user have the same PrimaryKey name Id

I have two class one for products and one for user

```
public class Product: EntityBase<Guid>
{
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{

}

builder.Entity<Rating>().HasIndex(r => new { r.User.Id, r.Product.Id }).HasName("IX_UserProductID").IsUnique(true);
```

Because the have the same name Id I get the following error.

An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

How can I best fix this probleme. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing this

First in my model Rating I added the following fields

```
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
```

And in MyDbCOntext I added this

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
         builder.Entity<Rating>().HasIndex(r => new { r.UserId, r.ProductID }).IsUnique(true);
    }
```

Comment: And notice that EF is smart enough to omit the normal index on the ProductID Foreign Key column in this case.